# Return the depth of the deepest node in a tree

Tags: python, algorithm, list, tree

This is my code for this problem

```
def height(t):
"""Return the depth of the deepest node in the tree."""
if isinstance(t, list):
    t = t[1:]
    if t != empty:
        return 1 + max([height(x) for x in t])
return 0
```

But it doesn't return the value as I expect. Can anyone figure this out?
Thanks.
And my tree method is:

```
def tree(entry, subtrees=[]):
    return lambda dispatch: entry if dispatch == 'entry' else list(subtrees)
def entry(tree):
    return tree('entry')
def subtrees(tree):
    return tree('subtrees')
```

Comment: example of a tree input?

Comment: @heinst height(tree(1, [tree(2), tree(3)]))

Comment: Because you don't close the comment,

Answer (score 0):

The param t of `height` function should be a tree, but you expect is a list `if isinstance(t, list)`, obviously, it isn't list, so just return 0.

because your `height` function is wrong. `height` function even didn't call the `entry` or `subtrees` function.

should get subtrees of tree, if empty, so return 1. if not empty, return 1 + max of height of subtrees of t.

I don't paste code, please check it yourself.